# Powering an External Phone Ringer - Straight Talk Home Service

Tags: power-supply, relay, telephone

My dad is having difficulty hearing his cordless phone ring in his shop, due to ambient noise. He has the phone connected to a Straight Talk home phone service device. So, there is no legacy analog line. I am trying to drive an external ringer that was built for an analog system. The Straight Talk jacks do not output sufficient current to drive the ringer.

Is there a way I could use a ring detector and relay? Does anything exist? How difficult would building something be? I have read that the old ringers require 90 VAC. Is that correct?

Sorry. Lots of questions in one post.

Thanks in advance for any info, ideas, suggestions, etc.

Comment: You can use a transistor or MOSFET to take the signal from the jack and drive the ringer. Google something like: "Drive DC motor with MOSFET" and replace the DC motor with the ringer in the actual application.

Answer (score 1):

For quite a while, Sparkfun had a series of wireless [desk phones](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/286) with the circuit housed in an old Bell System 500-style case.  So you could have an old-style black desk phone with a rotary dial and old-fashioned ringer, powered by a Li-Poly battery and connected to the telephone network by a cellular modem.

Since there was no phone line to activate the ringer, they built their own high-voltage circuit.  These phones have been retired from the Sparkfun catalog, but per their policy the information is still available including schematics and datasheet.

Here is a [link to the schematic](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Port-O-Rotary/Port-O-Rotary-v29-2.pdf).  The high-voltage ringing circuit is on page 3, which I have copied below:

[image]

Comment: Beware the Sparkfun schematics. Lot of errors. For example the above NJM2670 requires a 5 volt VCC supply, but Sparkfun is supplying only 3.8v via the mosfet switch.